# sticky navigation with in this svg scrolling animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

this The code I would like to use as a header on a website, all div tag "or anything I try to put in" are behind the svg even when I play with the Z-index.
I would like to have a sticky Navigation with simple text and cards under the header.

this is the html that i am using for the header for the website. this header works well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CodePen - 2020.6.5 Scrolltrigger SVG text mask</title>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<nav>
<a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
<a href="/css/">CSS</a> |
<a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
<a href="/python/">Python</a>
</nav>





<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<!-- This is a recreation of Unfold's (https://dribbble.com/unfold) parallax scene: 
https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/14268/screenshots/3275340/northface.gif -->
<div class="scrollDist absolute-divs">
<div class="main absolute-divs">
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id="m">
  <g class="cloud1">
    <rect fill="#fff" width="100%" height="801" y="799" />
    <image xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/cloud1Mask.jpg" width="1200" height="800"/>
   </g>
</mask>

<image class="sky" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/sky.jpg"  width="1200" height="590" />
<image class="mountBg" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/mountBg.png" width="1200" height="800"/>    
<image class="mountMg" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/mountMg.png" width="1200" height="800"/>    
<image class="cloud2" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/cloud2.png" width="1200" height="800"/>    
<image class="mountFg" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/mountFg.png" width="1200" height="800"/>
<image class="cloud1" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/cloud1.png" width="1200" height="800"/>
<image class="cloud3" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/721952/cloud3.png" width="1200" height="800"/>
<text fill="#fff" x="350" y="200">EXPLORE</text>
<polyline class="arrow" fill="#fff" points="599,250 599,289 590,279 590,282 600,292 610,282 610,279 601,289 601,250" />

 <g mask="url(#m)">
  <rect fill="#fff" width="100%" height="100%" />      
  <text x="350" y="200" fill="#162a43">FURTHER</text>
 </g>

 <rect id="arrowBtn" width="100" height="100" opacity="0" x="550" y="220" 
 style="cursor:pointer"/>
</svg>
 
</div>
</div>

<!-- partial -->
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/gsap-latest-beta.min.js'</script>
 <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/ScrollTrigger.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/ScrollToPlugin3.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

this is the js file i am using.

```
gsap.set('.main', {position:'fixed', background:'#fff', width:'100%', maxWidth:'1200px', 
top:0, left:'50%', x:'-50%'})
gsap.set('.scrollDist', {width:'100%', height:'200%'})
gsap.timeline({scrollTrigger:{trigger:'.scrollDist', start:'top top', end:'bottom bottom', 
scrub:1}})
.fromTo('.sky', {y:0},{y:-200}, 0)
.fromTo('.cloud1', {y:100},{y:-800}, 0)
.fromTo('.cloud2', {y:-150},{y:-500}, 0)
.fromTo('.cloud3', {y:-50},{y:-650}, 0)
.fromTo('.mountBg', {y:-10},{y:-100}, 0)
.fromTo('.mountMg', {y:-30},{y:-250}, 0)
.fromTo('.mountFg', {y:-50},{y:-600}, 0)

$('#arrowBtn').on('mouseenter', (e)=>{ gsap.to('.arrow', {y:10, duration:0.8, 
ease:'back.inOut(3)', overwrite:'auto'}); })
$('#arrowBtn').on('mouseleave', (e)=>{ gsap.to('.arrow', {y:0, duration:0.5, 
ease:'power3.out', overwrite:'auto'}); })
$('#arrowBtn').on('click', (e)=>{ gsap.to(window, {scrollTo:innerHeight, duration:1.5, 
ease:'power1.inOut'}); }) // scrollTo requires the ScrollTo plugin (not to be confused w/ 
ScrollTrigger)
```

this is the css I am using.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap');

 body, html {
 width:100%;
 background:rgb(71, 66, 66);
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size:99px;
 text-align:center;
}

.absolute-divs {
  position:absolute;
}

.nav{
   margin-top:100px;
}
```

Comment: A playground where you can set up the above-mentioned code would be helpful.

Comment: @ypahalajani how would I make a playground? Sorry for being so new to this.

Comment: Try this - https://codepen.io
This is a sandbox environment where you can recreate the above code and share a link (for the same) here so that someone can solve your problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/paulsanti/pen/zYweRob

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the code for navigation inside the ancestor/parent div which will be scrolling. I believe it is the div with class `scrollDist` like this

```html
    <div class="scrollDist">
      <nav class="nav">
        <a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
        <a href="/css/">CSS</a> |
        <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
        <a href="/python/">Python</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

2. Add styling for nav for making it sticky and on top of SVG.

```css
  .nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; /* This is required to keep it position like this with respect to the parent div which is the one with class `scrollDist` */
    z-index: 1; /* This creates a stacking index (to position it on top) */
  }
```

The nav should be on top of SVG and sticky now.